# grep-like command that output context records

Tags: grep

I'm looking for a grep-like command that outputs full records instead of a fixed number of context lines.

For instance:

```
grep -d record_delimiter PATTERN [FILE]
```

Logic:

- split the FILE in records according to the record_delimiter.
- If a match is found, print the whole record and skip to the next one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk` and change the record separator `RS`, like this:

awk -v RS= '/PATTERN/ { print $0"\n" }' [FILE]

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out [Recutils](http://www.gnu.org/s/recutils), which offers some pretty robust, database-like options for querying and manipulating files of records.